# Redirect from https domain to another https domain

Tags: server, apache2, mod-rewrite

How can i redirect apache from one "`https://domain1.com`" to "`https://www.domain2.com`"

I tried it as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1

        Redirect permanent /  https://www.domain2.com
......
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1

        Redirect permanent /  https://www.domain2.com
.....
</VirtualHost>
```

But it only redirects in "http" case like "`http://domain1.com`" goes to "`https://www.domain2.com`", doesn't work in case "`https://domain1.com`"?!

Comment: In your case, what's happening when you open `https://domain1.com` ? Do you have any SSL certificate added to your :443 virtualhost ?

Also, when you try : `curl -I https://domain1.com -k` what message gives you curl ?

Comment: Yes both domains have SSL certificates, output of curl says `curl: (7) Failed to connect to domain1.com port 443: Connection refused`

Comment: Is your apache version 2.2 or 2.4 ? If it is 2.4 , you should add : 
`Listen *:443` in your /etc/apache2/ports.conf and then restart apache. 

I think your problem is because, your apache doesn't run on port 443, but run only on port 80

Comment: Super! I'll put my comment as answer, so you can make your question answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add : `Listen *:443` in your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and then restart apache. I think your problem is because, your apache doesn't run on port 443, but run only on port 80